# How to add a class based on combination of class and its data-attribute value?

Tags: jquery

I have got 3 tabs as shown below

```
<div class="addonsQtyWrap">
   <ul>
      <li data-vendoritemid="703" data-tabid="1" class="tabclcik">Qty-1</li>
      <li data-vendoritemid="703" data-tabid="2" class="tabclcik">Qty-2</li>
      <li data-vendoritemid="703" data-tabid="3" class="tabclcik">Qty-3</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

I am able to fetch the tabnumber like 1 , 2 or 3 , based on the tabnumber how can i add active to the corresponding tab based on tabclcik and data-tabid value

I have tried this way but i am getting  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addClass' of undefined

```
$(this).find('.tabclcik').data('tabid'+tabnumber).addClass('active');
```

could you please let me know how to resolve this

This is my fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/tdzfhzjy/87/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the attribute selector:

```
$(this).find('.tabclcik[data-tabid="' + tabnumber + '"]').addClass('active');
```

Or you could use `filter()`:

```
$(this).find('.tabclcik').filter(function() {
    return $(this).data('tabid') == tabnumber;
}).addClass('active');
```

`filter` is a little quicker, but obviously more verbose.

Comment: Thanks , i have put up your code in the fiddle , but why is it not working there http://jsfiddle.net/tdzfhzjy/88/

Comment: If you do inspect element on the Qty tab , you will find <li data-vendoritemid="703" data-tabid="1" class="tabclcik">Qty-1</li> and <li data-vendoritemid="703" data-tabid="2" class="tabclcik">Qty-2</li>

Comment: please let me know if there is some other issue .

Comment: I think the issue is because `this` in the function does not relate to anything in the DOM. I would strongly suggest you restructure your code, as frankly at the moment it's a bit of a mess.

Comment: Thank you very much i resolved it $("#addonsWrap"+vendoritemsid).find('.tabclcik[data-tabid="' + tabnumber + '"]').addClass('active'); this way